# Eclipse workspace as htdocs in XAMPP not working in Mac?

Tags: macos, xampp, eclipse-pdt

I've bought a MacBook Air(I've been converted from a PC guy to a Mac) today and I have recently installed XAMPP and Eclipse for Mac and I try to set the workspace for Eclipse as the htdocs folder in XAMPP. I always get the warning:

Workspace in use or cannot be created, choose a different one!

The directory i try to set is /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs

I've been trying to set an another directory it works fine as long as it is not the one above. What have I done wrong? I want the directory above. Pls. help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is this:

1. Go into the htdocs folder and hit CMD+I to bring up the "Get Info" window
2. In this window, go to the bottom right and click on the padlock icon, enter your password to unlock the permissions settings in the window
3. You'll see a list of users and their respective permissions. Change the "admin"'s permission to "Read & Write"
4. Click the padlock once more to save your changes and lock the permissions for the htdocs folder
5. Start up Eclipse and then select htdocs as your workspace, and
6. Voila! You're done.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely a permissions issue.  The application may not be requesting admin rights to write to (or in some way control) that directory, it may just be silently failing.  Generally, you need to supply admin rights to modify anything under `/Applications/`.

I wouldn't recommend using `/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/` as your workspace anyway.  Your workspace should either be in your home directory (`Documents` or perhaps even `Library` though the former would be more intuitive), or in some other shared location if multiple users need to access it.  Bundling it with the application itself would risk losing the data during an application upgrade, or in some other way confusing the issue.

Why do you want your data in the `/Applications/` directory?

Comment: Hi David! I installed XAMPP in that directory /Application/XAMPP. I had the workspace in the htdocs folder because it is the easiest way to update and preview in the browser. At least when I used PC. I tried to move XAMPP folder to the Documents folder instead, but I got the same problem. I think the problem lies in the htdocs folder

Comment: @Woho87: Is there perhaps a `.lock` file hanging out somewhere in the workspace hierarchy?  That may be the simplest cause of the problem.

Comment: If i have the folder /Documents/workspace/"arbitrary folder". It works but than I cannot preview as easy as If I had htdocs as the workspace folder

Comment: @Woho87: What's involved in the "preview"?  It should just be configurable to point Eclipse and/or your web server to any folder you need.  At least, it was the last time I used XAMPP (some time ago).

Comment: how do point XAMPP to an another folder than htdocs? I tried to access the file httpd.conf but it showed there is no application that could open this file. I'm new on mac but in PC a texteditor could open all sorts of files

Comment: httpd.conf was under XAMPP/etc folder

Comment: @Woho87: A text editor can open that file.  You could associate the file with an editor by highlighting the file in Finder and pressing Command-i (to open the info window) and setting an application there.  Or you can just open TextEdit and manually open the file from within there.

Comment: ok thanks for the help David! I think I could cope with this problem now. If I had money I would reward you for your helpfulness

Comment: Wait I have problem saving because it is protected?

Comment: @Woho87: TextEdit should prompt you.  You could also save it to a temporary location and copy it over the original with Finder.  Or you could even just edit it on the console (using pico or something like that) with a `sudo` command if you need to.

Comment: David sorry for interrupting you but I got one last problem hopefully. I changed the directory to /Users/my_user_name/Documents/workspace in the httpd.conf. But now when I type in the url "localhost/my_website". I got the error message: 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /my_website on this server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that this workspace is locked.  The quick solution is to delete  /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/.metadata/.lock

The slightly longer solution is to try the following command whenever such a situation occurs:
find  /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs -name "*lock*" -exec echo {} \;

This will show you any file in that directory that has lock in the name.  Remember that hidden files start with a . (such as .lock or .metadata).

The even longer answer is that /Applications is outside of the userspace and should not be used for user documents (like code files).  These should ideally be moved to somewhere in /Users or into a directory specifically created for this purpose (such as /home or /shared).  I'm particularly fond of having a /Users/Shared directory for sharing files between accounts.